# Having api.mydomain.com redirect to the right server (e.g api2.mydomain.com, api3.mydomain.com etc.)

Tags: api, ms-access, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm working on a REST API (MS Web API) to expose some data that lies in our customers' databases. The customers are spread across 6-7 servers(containing their DB etc.), and each customer is identified by a key that's submitted along with every request.

I can identify which server the customer's database resides on based on the key from the request, so ideally I would just have for instance http://api.mydomain.com/products/ - and my products-controller would fetch data from the correct server.

HOWEVER... They are all MS Access databases and obviously not designed for this, so from what I've read, there's no straightforward way of making this happen. Connecting to an MS Access database that lies on a different server and (possibly) on a different network (servers are hosted somewhere else, I don't know whether they're connected in a LAN or not) seems near "impossible".

This seems to leave me with one option - host the api on all servers, which would scale horribly bad, be a nightmare to maintain - and in general feels like a really bad idea. However, I don't know if I have a choice.

By going with this last option, I was hoping I could at least let our customers use http://api.mydomain.com/products, and just get redirected to the appropriate API (api2, api3, api4 etc.). How can I achieve this in IIS?

Any advice on the architecture here would be greatly appreciated, as the developer in me really want to avoid doing it this way!!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to copy the remote database files to a central location where you can have normal file access.

Or to upgrade the backend databases to SQL Server Express. These can live anywhere: on-site at the remote locations, or one central server, or hosted at, say, Amazon AWS or Azure.